# Error : Package 'mongodb' has no installation candidate

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, beagleboneblack

I am unable to apt-get install any packages on cloud9 for my BeagleBone because `E: Package 'mongodb' has no installation candidate`. I have not been able to get any packages to work due to the same error. I have updated, upgraded, rebooted, but nothing has worked.

More informations about my BBG :

```
debian@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9$ uname -a
Linux beaglebone 4.9.82-ti-r102 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 22 01:16:12 UTC 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux


debian@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9$ cat /etc/*-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Also, here is my sources.list file :

```
GNU nano 2.7.4               File: /etc/apt/sources.list                                                                    

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free

#deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib non-free
##deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib non-free

#Kernel source (repos.rcn-ee.com) : https://github.com/RobertCNelson/linux-stable-rcn-ee
#
#git clone https://github.com/RobertCNelson/linux-stable-rcn-ee
#cd ./linux-stable-rcn-ee
#git checkout `uname -r` -b tmp
#
deb [arch=armhf] http://repos.rcn-ee.com/debian/ stretch main
#deb-src [arch=armhf] http://repos.rcn-ee.com/debian/ stretch main
deb http://debian.mirror.ac.za/debian stretch main 
#deb-src http://debian.mirror.ac.za/debian stretch main
```

Comment: Have you done an `apt-get update` ?  Does `apt-cache search packagename` find anything?  What about `apt-cache madison packagename` ?

Comment: Can you show the output of `apt update` and subsequent installation of a package?

Comment: @ivanivan I need to install mongodb on my BBG, I try apt-cache search mongodb` but I find other packages of mongodb and apt-cache madison mongodb` does not display anything.

Comment: @Henrik I try that, but it's not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MongoDB isn’t supported on `armhf`, the architecture your BeagleBone uses; see [#836435](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=836435) for details. As a result it’s no longer available in the Debian repositories for Debian 9 and later.